# store username into a variable in mysql sql file

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql sql file that uses the user in multiple spots. I would like to be able to define a variable that stores the user so I can use it in multiple places.

My sql file looks as follows...

```
SET @username = "'myapp'@'localhost'";
DROP USER if exists @username;
DROP DATABASE if exists mydb;
CREATE DATABASE mydb;

use mydb;

CREATE TABLE mydb.table1 (
    match_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    board BINARY(64) NOT NULL
);

 CREATE USER @username IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.table1 TO @username;
```

But this is definitely not working...

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '@username IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: The keyword USER seems to be reserved by MySQL. Try to use @username for the variable. Also what error do you get?

Comment: updated with error

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use prepared statements (which are a bit more complicated), but if you specifically want to use a user-defined variable as a drop-in replacement for a username as you described, the answer is no.

This was reported as a bug here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28406